# Gitlab call REST API via curl not working

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

In my .gitlab-ci.yml file I want to send a notification to a WebexTeams or Spark room after each state. I can do this through a curl command (because webex teams or Spark use a REST API)

```
image:
  name: hashicorp/terraform:light
  entrypoint:
    - '/usr/bin/env'
    - 'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'

before_script:
  - rm -rf .terraform
  - terraform --version
  - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
  - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
  - terraform init

.webexteams_variables: &webexteams_variables
  roomId = "Y2l***NGQy"

.webexteams_send: &webexteams_send
  script:  
  - curl --request POST --header 'Authorization: Bearer $bearer' --form 'roomId=$roomId' --form 'text=$msg' https://api.ciscospark.com/v1/messages 

stages:
  - validate

validate:
  stage: validate
  script:
    - terraform validate
  variables:
    msg: "Validation complete"
    <<: *webexteams_variables
  <<: *webexteams_send
```

I'm getting an issue

> Status: syntax is incorrect  Error: jobs:validate:script config should
>   be an array of strings or a string

Removing the quotes is fixing this issue but then I get the following

> Running with gitlab-runner 12.0.1 (0e5417a3)   on
>   gitlab-runner iRWmYNFc Using Docker executor with image
>   hashicorp/terraform:light ... Pulling docker image
>   hashicorp/terraform:light ... Using docker image
>   sha256:0cd71852a450fe70bb72b7f8084b11d7b8ecd34027e0cb1521680aa426415737
>   for hashicorp/terraform:light ... Running on
>   runner-iRWmYNFc-project-11-concurrent-0 via wauterw-gitlab-runner...
>   /bin/bash: line 69: export: `<<=roomId =
>   "Y2l***Qy"':
>   not a valid identifier /bin/bash: line 69: export:`<<=roomId =
>   "Y2l***Qy"':
>   not a valid identifier ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

Any idea how to fix this? 
If there are different ways to achieve this I would be interested to hear about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The yaml is invalid, there is something wrong with your anchor : you include `webexteams_send` containing a `script:` bloc but your `validate` job contains already a `script:` bloc.

If a correct that error, this `.gitlab-ci.yml` is valid :

```
image:
  name: hashicorp/terraform:light
  entrypoint:
    - '/usr/bin/env'
    - 'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'

before_script:
  - rm -rf .terraform
  - terraform --version
  - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
  - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
  - terraform init

.webexteams_variables: &webexteams_variables
  roomId: "Y2l***NGQy"

stages:
  - validate

validate:
  stage: validate
  script:
    - terraform validate
    - 'curl --request POST --header "Authorization: Bearer $bearer" --form "roomId=$roomId" --form "text=$msg" https://api.ciscospark.com/v1/messages'
  variables:
    msg: "Validation complete"
    <<: *webexteams_variables
```

Note : the curl is between single quote because "the colon in the curl is interpreted as yaml's map key, because the whole shell command is not in quotes" see [this](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support-forum/issues/3109#note_180753221) related issue

Comment: Thanks a lot. The quotes were indeed mixed up. Works like a charm now.